# How to loop through all textfield that is not disabled

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input of type text that are radomly enabled or disabled.. i want to loop through all the input that is not disabled.. TIA!

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [enabled-selector](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) and [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) find find out enabled elements and then use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through them

```
$('input[type="text"]:enabled')
```

another way is to use the [text-selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/),

```
$('input:text:enabled')
```

this is the preferred way because

```
$('<input>').is('[type=text]'); // false
$('<input>').is(':text'); // true
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LdVJd/)

Comment: @Sergio also see the update and the problem with both our first approaches

Comment: tnx....it works for me..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("input:not(:disabled)").each(function(){
    $(this).val("No Disable");
});
```

specific for type text which are enabled:

```
$("input[type=text]:enabled").each(function(){
    $(this).val("No Disable");
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VLjxQ/1/

Comment: Great answer except the `disabled` attribute in your fiddle should either be set to "disabled" or "" (empty string).  [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "input[type='text']:not([disabled])" ).each(function() {
  // found one
  // do something
});
```

The important thing here is the jQuery [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector which, in this case, selects all input elements that do not contain the disabled attribute.